# How can I dynamically insert values in my environment file?

Tags: angular, angular-module

I have a requirement where I need to make api call, and based on the response I want to insert the values in my `environment.ts` file.

How can I achieve this? I can't find a way to make a call in my `app.module.ts` file

I have the following method which works, but how can I call this method in `app.module.ts` file ?

```
export function authServiceFactory() {
  return async () => {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch('url').then(res => res.json())
        .then((response: EnvironmentPropertiesPojo) => {
          const config: EnvironmentPropertiesPojo = response;
          resolve({
            api: config.api,
            healthCheck: config.healthCheck,
            logo: config.logo,
            logoutRedirection: config.logoutRedirection,
            sessionIdle: config.sessionIdle,
            sessionTimeout: config.sessionTimeout,
            url: config.url
          })
        }).catch(error => {
          reject('Something went wrong. Please try again later.');
        });
    });
    const config: EnvironmentPropertiesPojo = await promise;
    console.log('config', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(config)));
    environment.api = config.api;
    environment.healthCheck = +config.healthCheck;
    environment.logo = config.logo;
    environment.logoutRedirection = config.logoutRedirection;
    environment.sessionIdle = +config.sessionIdle;
    environment.sessionTimeout = +config.sessionTimeout;
    environment.url = config.url;
    console.log('environment after', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(environment)));
  };
}
```

Comment: Changing the env props is not a better approach, why can't you create a service file and create the variables there, change and access in the runtime.

Comment: Because i am using in the one project authService - i need to do ths in app.module.ts file

Comment: You want to call this method from app.module.ts in runtime ?